# C, Flex and Bison: error: conflicting types for ‘yyerror’

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm doing a project in C with Flex and Bison, but I found an error during the compile.

Here is the error:

```
A_Sintactico.yy:186:6: error: conflicting types for ‘yyerror’
In file included from A_Sintactico.yy:3:0:
A_Lexico.l:15:8: note: previous declaration of ‘yyerror’ was here
 extern yyerror(char*);
    ^
```

Code of yyerror in A_Sintactico.yy:

```
void yyerror(char* mens){
    extern int numlin;
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sintactico en la linea %i %s\n", numlin, mens);
}
```

Code of yyerror in A_Lexico.l

```
extern yyerror(char*);
```

What is happening?, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct declaration is

`void yyerror(const char* mens);`

And the function definition should be the same:

`void yyerror(const char* mens)
{ … }`

`extern` is not necessary, although it doesn't hurt. But the return type is obligatory.

Changing the argument to `const char*` is not necessary, but it is highly recommended, since `yyerror` may be called with a string literal as an argument.

Comment: i have tried with your solution and it doesn't work... if i use void yyerror(const char*); removing extern the problem is the same, but if i change the function i have more problems

Comment: @juanjo: the declaration and the definition need to be the same. They should both be `void yyerror(const char* mens)`. I'll update the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `extern` version looks oldish. Implicit return is `int` in that case not `void` . You 'd have to get the two consistent.